# Unable to get struts2 s:select tag value to the action class where action class is called from a s:url

Tags: url, select, null, struts2

I have an iterator with all s:property values and one drop down and one url link. Please find below code.

```
<s:iterator value="#hmapValue.quotesList" status="stat1" var="qt">
                        

                            <tr>
                            <td><span><s:property value="#stat1.count" /></span></td>
                                <td><span> <s:property value="#qt.nameOfCourier" /></span>
                                
                                </td>
                                <td><span> <s:property value="#qt.total" /></span></td>
                                <td><span> <s:property value="#qt.priceInsuranceEx" /></span></td>
                                <td><span> <s:property value="#qt.fee" /></span></td>
                                <td><span> <s:property value="#qt.appliedGst" /></span></td>
                                <td><span> <s:property value="#qt.insuredAmount" /></span></td>
                                <td><span> <s:property value="#qt.service" /></span></td>
                                <td><span> <s:property value="#qt.transitTime" /></span></td>
                                <td>
                                    <div>

            <s:select list="pickUpDates" id="picupdate"  listKey="code" listValue="name" value="code" headerKey="-1" headerValue="--Please Select--" />
                        </div>
                                </td>
                                <td><s:set var="picTim" value="#qt.pickUpTime" />
                                    <div>
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>

                                                <td><div>
                                                        <strong>From Time:</strong> <span> <s:property
                                                                value="#picTim.fromTime" /></span>
                                                    </div></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div>
                                                        <strong>To Time:</strong> <span><s:property
                                                                value="#picTim.toTime" /></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                                

                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div></td>
<td>
<s:url action="confirmBooking" var="confBkng" >
<s:param name="courier" value="#qt.nameOfCourier" />
<s:param name="pickupDate" value="#qt.pickUpDate" />
</s:url> 
<a href="<s:property value="#confBkng" />" >Confirm</a>
```

When I am calling action class from above url tag I am able to get the courier value but pickupDate is always null. Please Can anyone tell what is the reason for null value and how to resolve this.

Comment: I don't see anything called `pickUpDate` anywhere, so it's difficult to understand what you're asking.

Comment: It is a param name in the url tag at the bottom of the code. I am getting this param pickupDate value as null but i was able to get courier - which is another param in the same url tag. Can you please check it and let me know what wrong i am doing.

Comment: It should be the selected value of the s:select tag

Comment: I don’t understand; why would it be that? It’ll be whatever it’s value is when the page is rendered on the server side.

Comment: In the iterator all values are printed as s:property only pickupDates is the list of dates which is the only one input field. I am able to get this dates list in the drop down but selected value is not coming into the action class. I am calling the action through the url tag as shown in the above code.

Comment: I don’t  understand. The JSP tags are rendered on the server, before the page is sent to the client. If you want to submit a form, submit a form.